# Clear Cache data in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, infrastructure, kubernetes-health-check

Is there any way of viewing cache data in kubernetes cluster ? Does it get stored in a folder somewhere or can It be shown via a monitoring tool (Prometheus) ?
And how to clean the cache data in k8s cluster ?

Comment: what do you mean under "kubernetes cache data"?

Answer (score 1):

There is cache directory in Kubernetes; however, it is held within the Master Node. As shown in this [github link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59356), the issue was found when debugging the kube-controller which is handled by the Master Node.

I am not familiar with Amazon's cloud service; however, within GKE, the Master node is a managed service and customers do not have access to it. So to answer your question, yes there is a cache directory in Kubernetes, but you cannot view it within GKE.

Answer (score 0):

with this command you can see the buff/cahe memory for each pod

```
kubectl exec -it my-cluster-kafka-1 -- bash
```

and then just `top`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could specify which kind of cache data you would like to clear, and what you would like to achieve.

For kubectl there is a default cache directory`$HOME/.kube/cache` [1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/#:%7E:text=Default%3A%20%22%24HOME/.kube/cache%22), and `$HOME/.kube/http-cache` for the http cache [2](https://v1-17.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/#:%7E:text=%24HOME/.kube/http-cache).

There’s also a cache server like Memcached that is used for caching web content in k8s reference [3](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/deploying-memcached-on-kubernetes-engine).